# How to Save a FCM token in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am following [this](https://github.com/probelalkhan/android-push-using-firebase-cloud-messaging/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/simplifiedcoding/firebasecloudmessaging/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java) to register my deivce in Firebase

Here I am trying to display and save the notification token

```
    public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        storeToken(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void storeToken(String token) {
        //saving the token on shared preferences
        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).saveDeviceToken(token);
    }
}
```

When I try to register it Always Says Token `Token not generated`   form 
[MainActivity](https://github.com/probelalkhan/android-push-using-firebase-cloud-messaging/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/simplifiedcoding/firebasecloudmessaging/MainActivity.java)

So Here My Application is connected to Firebase.. and I know that `FirebaseInstanceIdService` is Deprecated I also tried with this

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String refreshedToken) {
        refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().getResult().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        storeToken(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void storeToken(String token) {
        //saving the token on shared preferences
        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).saveDeviceToken(token);
    }
}
```

But Still same token is not generated

Comment: Does it show in the window log?

Comment: read these ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403162/store-token-for-fcm  and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454501/firebase-fcm-force-ontokenrefresh-to-be-called

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add this in your code..

```
    public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("TOKEN_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String token = prefs.getString("token", "");

        Log.e("NEW_INACTIVITY_TOKEN", token);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(MyActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                    String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                    Log.e("newToken", newToken);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("TOKEN_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    if (token!=null){
                       editor.putString("token", newToken);
                       editor.apply();
                    }

                }
            });
        }

    }


}
```

Firebase Tokens are called once when the app is installed and runned for the first time so ***ignore the Saving the data or running this Activity/Service once the Data is Saved with Shared Prefs***

Comment: Yes now this works fine.. no effect on every time I open the app.. and token is saved successfully

Answer (score 18):

The `onTokenRefresh`/`onNewToken` method will only be called when a new token is generated.

Quite often (especially during development) your app will already have generated an Instance ID token before you added the service. So `onTokenRefresh`/`onNewToken` will not be called, and you won't have a token in your shared preferences.

For this reason you should get the token directly from your main activity with `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()` as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token). This will pick up the token that was last generated. From there on you use `onTokenRefresh`/`onNewToken` to respond to token *changes*.

Comment: Yes now I understand that Token only Generated only when The App is installed First time... After Getting Token I am Trying to add Shared prefs,,, But After uninstalling Its worked fine..

Comment: So Without Uninstall Can I get Token every time When I run??? If already Token Generated I wont call the Service Which generates Token

Comment: An uninstall indeed wipes the token. So upon a reinstall your `onTokenRefresh`/`onNewToken` gets called. As I said in my answer, if you simply want to get the token in your main activity, call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()`. If that doesn't result in a token, it hasn't been generated yet and your `onTokenRefresh`/`onNewToken` will get called eventually.

Comment: Yup thanks,,, with your and @MLN Now I got It.. Thanks

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you help me with the same issue. My token is not generating even on first run. Here is the link to my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658578/firebase-fcm-token-not-generating?noredirect=1#comment92247828_52658578

Answer (score 2):

No need to Use `getToken()` **new token already returned by `onNewToken` argument**

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String refreshedToken) {
    // No need to assign refreshedToken with getToken,
    // this method called when token refreshed then use returned refreshedToken directly,
    // use `instanceIdResult.getToken()` described below when you need to use token later throw app usage.

    // refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().getResult().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    storeToken(refreshedToken);
}
```

**[getToken(); is also deprecated](https://medium.com/android-school/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated-50651f17a148)**

> Get Token in your Activity : .getToken(); is also deprecated if you
>   need to get token in your activity then use as following:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MyActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
           String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
           Log.e("newToken",newToken);

     }
 });
```

Comment: your answer is not actual anymore (they seem to change firebase lietarlly every few months, half of their docs does not work even if you copy paste it and tons of methods are deprecated or completely different).

Answer (score 2):

May be it takes some time to generate token. If you don't get it you can generate it as follow:
(Reference:https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?authuser=0)

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() 
 {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) 
   {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", 
                                task.getException());
                                return;
                            }

                            // Get new Instance ID token
                            String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                            //Here you will surely get the token so store it in 
                            //sharedpreference for future use

                        }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
just uninstall and reinstall app
because token is not generated everytime you play the app.
It's generated when you clear sharePref or reinstall.

Comment: Yes Now this is Worked fine Token Generated,,,But without Uninstall Is it not possible???