# Xamarin.Android - FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated and OnNewToken() not working

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement OnNewToken() method from FirebaseMessagingService in my Xamarin Android project that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging since `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and `OnTokenRefreshed()` are deprecated.

I tried this

```
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class MessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
        public override void OnNewToken(string token)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
            SendRegistrationToServer(token);
        }

        public void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
        {
            ...
        }

    }
```

But my OnNewToken() is not hit. What am I doing wroing. Do i need to include anything in my Android manifest file? I cannot find any documents specific to Xamarin Android about this update. Please help. Thank you so much.

Also, please provide method to get token from Activity as well. Thanks

Comment: check this it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834864/how-to-save-a-fcm-token-in-android

Comment: @NileshRathod it appears to be for Java. But for Xamarin.Android, its similar, but syntactically, a bit, different. Not working out in my case. Thanks Nilesh.

Comment: if you found solution than you can post as an answer so it can help others

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it as an answer so it can help others.

Comment: There was a bug in the first preview builds. Simply upgrading the to the newer versions will solve this. Also make sure you install the same version for all, else you will get NullPointers

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity, Android.Gms.Tasks.IOnSuccessListener
{
        public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
        {
                var token = result.Class.GetMethod("getToken").Invoke(result).ToString();
                Log.Debug(TAG, "InstanceID token: " + token);
        }
}
```

and simply call

```
FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.GetInstanceId().AddOnSuccessListener(this);
```