# FCM token retrieval [Xamarin] - update because of the deprecated method

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, "FirebaseInstanceIdService" gives a warning it is depreciated and obsolete.

"OnTokenRefresh()" doesn't work anymore, and we should instead use:

```
   public void onNewToken(String s) 
   {
        Log.d("FCM_TOKEN", s);
        // save in SharedPreference for future use
   }
```

But - in order to get the token in MainActivity, I've previously used:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token
```

This is also deprecated, and I could only find Java solution for this:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MyActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
 @Override
 public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
       String token = instanceIdResult.getToken();
       Log.d("FCM_TOKEN",token);
 }
});
```

Could you please let me know how can I get the current token in C# (Xamarin)?

---

Question #2: is this OK implementation for `OnNewToken()` in C#:

```
public class MessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    public override void OnNewToken(string token)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
        SendToServer(token);
    }

}
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -2):

**1)** I'm also using Firebase Cloud Messaging for my project. I don't think `FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token` is deprecated for two reasons. First, I don't have any warnings as you said. Second, [FCM Notifications Walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin) from Microsoft is updated recently, and it does not mention that property is deprecated.

**2)** `FirebaseMessagingService` is to handle notifications( or messages) received, not to handle tokens. For example, if your app server is sending a message ([how to send a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages) ) to a client (a device), `FirebaseMessagingService` is where you receive and handle the message at client. Also, if you **right click** on the class **FirebaseMessagingService** -> **"Go To Definition"**, you would see that there **isn't** a `OnNewToken()` to override.

Q1 and Q2 come together, I'm guessing you want something like below  to retrieve a registration token and send it to your app server.

```cs
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
    {
       // send token to app server  
    }
}
```

The code above extracted from the walkthrough. My explanations are brief and incomplete. You should read the walkthrough to have a better understanding.

Comment: FirebaseInstanceIdService is obsolete/deprecated. That's the warning I'm getting in Visual Studio, after updating all the packages (especially the ones related to Firebase).

Please see this link ---> https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/136542/fcm-token-for-push-notifications-firebaseinstanceid-intance-token-obsolete (Xamarin Forums) ;

and this one ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834864/how-to-save-a-fcm-token-in-android (stackoverflow)

Comment: Firebase is not a Microsoft product, don't trust their documentation for Google's deprecations.