# Firebase fcm token not generating

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to integrate fcm for having push notification functionality in my app. But the problem is my fcm token is not getting generated at all. I used  the same code I used in this project into a new project and it worked without any issue.

But with this project I have tried everything to no result at all.

I tried with both the deprecated `onTokenRefresh()` method as well as the new `onNewToken()` method but none of them is working for me.

Below is the code for the same.

```
    public class CustomFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.

        Log.d("Firebase", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d("Firebase", "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d("Firebase", "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.d("token",s);
    }
}
```

And this is the code with onTokenRefresh() method

```
    public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("Firebase", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

I have declared both services in the manifest too.

```
<service android:name=".notification.CustomFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".notification.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**What I have tried**

1. Deleted the project on console and creating again
2. Copying whole project to a new folder and open again in Android Studio
3. Tried with both of the above service
4. Tried calling `FirebaseInstanceId.getToken()` but this gives null pointer exception.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the implementation errors, have a look at how instance ID works: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/, check the chapter *Instance ID lifecycle* at the bottom.

I can see 2 points where it might go wrong:

1. You don't have a connection with the Google servers. Check if you have a working internet connection by opening the device and opening a webpage. Also take proxies and firewalls into account, those might block your traffic (for example, if you are in China, the Great Firewall might block your connection with the Instance ID servers).
2. Make sure you don't already have a token. This is quite a common error. You implement the ID token service, and run the app. It works fine, now you want to send the token to the server, and write the code for it. When you run the app again, you will see no connection to the server, and think there's an issue with your implementation.
   What actually happened, is that you already got your token on the first run, and it was cached by the app. The second time it already has a token, and the `onNewToken()` will not be called.
   If you uninstall the app, and install it again, it will ask for a new token on launch.

Comment: I have checked both points multiple time. If I try to get token using getToken method my app crashes with NPE. So that confirms there is no token generated. I even tried using app with VPNS too

Comment: @Daniel Zolnari is right. Mine was the second case.

Comment: I am getting "Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later." in the first run itself. any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solution to my problem. I got this hint when I was trying to integrate OneSignal notification sdk. The problem was that I had the below code in the application tag of manifest.

```
tools:node="replace"
```

This was written in OneSignal docs.

> Make sure you are not replacing the  tag in your AndroidManifest.xml with tools:node="replace"

As OneSignal was also internally using FireBase I thought to give it a try with the firebase directly and it worked after I removed it.

Hope this will help someone else too

Answer (score 1):

The `onTokenRefresh`/`onNewToken` methods are only called *when* a token is generated. Most of the time a token just exists, and is not modified. During that time, `onTokenRefresh`/`onNewToken` won't be called.

So most likely, your token was generated when you first add the app, before you had the `onTokenRefresh`/`onNewToken`. So to now get the token, you can do two things:

1. Uninstall and reinstall the app. Deleting the app will delete the existing token, then it will generate a new token on the reinstall, and call your `onTokenRefresh`/`onNewToken`.
2. Also request the token in e.g. your `MainActivity.onCreate`.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       String iidToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
       Log.d("Firebase", "Got token: " + iidToken);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for replying. My main issue was that I had tools:replace added in application tag in manifest. That was somehow stopping firebase from creating token. Can you tell reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Nilesh Rathod FirebaseInstanceIdService is depreciated. So no you need only one service in the manifest.

Try this way.
1. First Create a Service

```
public class YourService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "2")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_icon)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (NOTIFICATION_ID > 1073741824) {
        NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    }
    Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, mNotifyBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Now add this to Manifest

```
<service
   android:name=".YourService"
   android:exported="false">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: I said that to Nilesh too. I have tried both ways. None of them worked.Please try to read the complete question.

Comment: Read question properly once again

Comment: Deprecated means that it still works, but it will be removed in the future, so you should start migrating to the new API.

Answer (score 0):

the generate of token for firebase is in first install of app or when you delete the cache for app ,this example of code work for me 
     public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor1;
private static final String PREF_NAME1 = "prefs_token";
private static final String KEY_FCM = "devices_token";
//this method will be called
//when the token is generated
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME1, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor1 = sharedPreferences1.edit();
    super.onTokenRefresh();

    //now we will have the token
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    editor1.putString(KEY_FCM,token.toString());
     editor1.apply();

    //for now we are displaying the token in the log
    //copy it as this method is called only when the new token is generated
    //and usually new token is only generated when the app is reinstalled or the data is cleared
    Log.d("MyRefreshedToken", token);
    String device_token = sharedPreferences1.getString(KEY_FCM, "");

}
```

}

Comment: I have mentioned that in my question that I have tried multiple times by uninstalling/installing app again. I know token is only generated first time, but in my case it is not even generating for the first time.

Comment: Does the device you are testing on have the latest Google Play Services installed?

Answer (score 0):

Create two java classes and one interface in APP

1. Interface:

   ```
   public interface FCMTokenInterface {
       void onTokenReceived(String token);
       void onFailure();
   }
   ```
2. Token Listener Class:

   ```
       public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
            private static FCMTokenInterface fcmTokenCallback;
           private static Handler handlerOs = new Handler();
           private static int delay=20000;
           private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
           private static final String FRIENDLY_ENGAGE_TOPIC = "friendly_engage";

           @Override
           public void onTokenRefresh() {
               String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
               Log.d(TAG, "FCM Token: 3" + token);
   //putting token in preference
               Prefs.putString(Constant.FCM_TOKEN,token);
               FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()
                       .subscribeToTopic(FRIENDLY_ENGAGE_TOPIC);
           }

           public static void setCallback(FCMTokenInterface callback) {

               try {
                   String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                   if (token != null && !token.isEmpty()) {
   ```

   //putting token in preference
                           Prefs.putString(Constant.FCM_TOKEN,token);
                           callback.onTokenReceived(token);
                           return;
                       }
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       retry(callback);
                       Log.v("SetCallback EXP= ", e.toString());
                   }
                   fcmTokenCallback = callback;
           //        startHandler();
               }

   ```
           public static void retry(FCMTokenInterface callback)
           {
               setCallback(callback);
           }

           private static void startHandler() {
               handlerOs.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       retry(fcmTokenCallback);
       //                fcmTokenCallback.onFailure();
                       fcmTokenCallback = null;
                   }
               }, delay);
           }

           private static void clearHandler() {
               handlerOs.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
           }

       }
   ```
3. Message Receiving Class:

   ```
   public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
   private static final String TAG = "MyFMService";
   String CHANNEL_ID = "com.app.app";
   NotificationChannel mChannel;
   private NotificationManager mManager;
   private String title, msg, actionCode;
   private int badge = 0;

   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
   @Override
   public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       // Handle data payload of FCM messages.
       Log.d(TAG, "FCM Message Id: " + remoteMessage.getMessageId());
       Log.d(TAG, "FCM Notification Message: " + remoteMessage.getData() + "...." +
               remoteMessage.getFrom());
       if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
           Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
           JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);
           //Log.e("JSON_OBJECT", object.toString());
           title = object.optString("title","");
           actionCode = object.optString("action_code", "");
           msg = object.optString("body", "");
           if (remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("badge")) {
               badge = Integer.parseInt(remoteMessage.getData().get("badge"));
               //Log.d("notificationNUmber", ":" + badge);
               setBadge(getApplicationContext(), badge);
               Prefs.putBoolean(Constant.HAS_BADGE,true);
           }
           if (!(title.equals("") && msg.equals("") && actionCode.equals(""))) {
               createNotification(actionCode, msg, title);
           }
           else {
               //Log.e("Notification", "Invalid Data");
           }
       }
   }

   public void createNotification(String action_code, String msg, String title) {
       Intent intent = null;
       intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra(Constant.ACTION_CODE, action_code);
       PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
           NotificationChannel androidChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                   title, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
           // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel should display notification lights
           androidChannel.enableLights(true);
           // Sets whether notification posted to this channel should vibrate.
           androidChannel.enableVibration(true);
           // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this channel
           androidChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);

           // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel appear on the lockscreen or not
           androidChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
           getManager().createNotificationChannel(androidChannel);
           Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                   .setContentTitle(title)
                   .setContentText(msg)
                   .setTicker(title)
                   .setShowWhen(true)
                   .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_small_notification)
                   .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                           R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round))
                   .setAutoCancel(true)
                   .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

           getManager().notify(101, nb.build());

       } else {
           try {

               @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "LocalSuppress"}) android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                       .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_small_notification)
                       .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                               R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round))
                       .setContentTitle(title)
                       .setTicker(title)
                       .setContentText(msg)
                       .setShowWhen(true)
                       .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                       .setLights(0xFF760193, 300, 1000)
                       .setAutoCancel(true).setVibrate(new long[]{200, 400});
                       /*.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                               + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.tone));*/


               NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
               notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis() /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
           } catch (SecurityException se) {
               se.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }

   private NotificationManager getManager() {
       if (mManager == null) {
           mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       }
       return mManager;
   }
   }
   ```
4. Implement Interface on your Splash:

   ```
   class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FCMTokenInterface {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

       MyInstanceIDListenerService.setCallback(this)
   }
     override fun onFailure() {
           Log.d("Token", "Unable to get token.")
       }

       override fun onTokenReceived(token: String?) {
           Log.d("Token", token)
           Prefs.putString(Constant.FCM_TOKEN, token)
       }
   }
   ```
5. Manifest under Application TAG

   ```
   <service android:name="fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
           </intent-filter>
       </service>
       <service android:name="fcm.MyInstanceIDListenerService">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
           </intent-filter>
       </service>

       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
           android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
           android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
   ```

Comment: I am not getting the token that's the main issue.

Comment: Please read and Implement the Above code you will get Token instantly guaranteed and never forgot to implement interface on SplashScreen