# how to get the Context Inside the FirebaseMessagingService?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app and It Uses FCM for sending and receiving messages. I have implemented every thing as suggested in docs.

Now on generation of token I want to save that into the Shared Preferrences. but it is giving error on that .

Consider the name of class is like

```
public class MyFirebaseMsgAndTokenService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "C_MyFirebaseIIDService";

@Override
public void onNewToken(String newToken) {
    super.onNewToken(newToken);
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + newToken);
    CustomSharedPreferences customSharedPreferences = new CustomSharedPreferences(this); // giving error on this
    String oldToken = customSharedPreferences.getStringData(FCM_GENERATED_TOKEN);
    sendRegistrationToServer(newToken,oldToken);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    try {

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}}
```

***I really want to save the token into my app here in this service. Please tell me why I am not able to get the reference/Context ?***

**update: My CustomSharedPrefernces is a class which is saving data in to sharedPrefernces**

```
public class CustomSharedPreferences {

public static final String FCM_GENERATED_TOKEN = "FCM_GENERATED_TOKEN";


private static CustomSharedPreferences mCustomSharedPreferences;
private final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public static CustomSharedPreferences getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mCustomSharedPreferences == null) {
        mCustomSharedPreferences = new CustomSharedPreferences(context);
    }
    return mCustomSharedPreferences;
}


public CustomSharedPreferences(Context context) {
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}}
```

**Update:**

> error: "android.content.context in CustomSharedPreferences can not be applied to com.myprojectname.MyFireBaseMsgAndTokenService"

Comment: What specific error are you getting? Post the log.

Comment: FirebaseMessagingService extends EnhancedIntentService which then extends Service. Using `this` should work. If that doesn't, type `context` and check your auto complete

Comment: Post snippet of `CustomSharedPreferences`.

Comment: @Jay posted.......

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me. Check your imports, is it `import android.content.Context;` in `CustomSharedPreferences.java`? Where  exactly is that error shown? Have you tried to use `Build>Clean Project`? Is your gradle in sync? What version of `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:??` are you using?

Comment: @zapl to me the error is fine and my apps run fine, but it showing error in editor

Comment: Maybe if you restart Android studio. There should be no error if everything is correct with your code, especially if it compiles and runs fine

Comment: Not understanding the downvoting on his question. I have a similar issue when my app is in the background or closed. We want to show notifications but drawables and such are not available as there is not really a context

Answer (score 19):

You can see my firebase notification handling here:

[image]

```
public UserPreferences(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
```

You can use simply use `this` or`getApplicationContext()` to get the context

Comment: it gives me error saying "android.content.context in CustomSharedPreferences can not be applied to com.myprojectname.MyFireBaseMsgAndTokenService"

Comment: I just saw that you are using old Firebase version, Please check my updated answer.

Comment: it is not accisible and I am not using old fcm

Comment: @Androidteem check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834864/how-to-save-a-fcm-token-in-android

Comment: doing exactly like this but I do not know why that error is coming , see the updated answer

Comment: using static context that defined in application class worked for me

Answer (score 3):

```
FirebaseMessagingService extends Service
```

and

```
Service extends ContextWrapper
```

and

```
ContextWrapper extends Context
```

so it is a `Context` as well, so use `MyFirebaseMessagingService.this` or simply `this`.

Comment: Having same issue as OP, and for me it says FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.iid.zzb which extends Object :/

Comment: Have we find any solution?

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: I'm in the same situation, someone has any solution?

Answer (score 3):

For me, I just upgraded my Firebase Messaging to the latest (which during this time of writing 20.2.0).

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'`

Then somehow suddenly I can pass `this` again.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still struggling with this problem, here is the solution:

To be able to get the context inside any Service you should do that in onCreate method, otherwise you'll face the `NullPointerException`

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code, here is your CustomSharedPreferences class.

```
public class SharedHelper
 {
    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public static void putKey(Context context, String Key, String Value) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Key, Value);
        editor.apply();

    }

    public static String getKey(Context context, String Key) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(Key, "");
    }
}
```

after that add following code add in FirebaseMessagingService.class

```
    @Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);

    @SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
    String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    Log.d("DEVICE_ID: " , deviceId);
    Log.d("FCM_TOKEN",s);

    SharedHelper.putKey(this, "device_token", s);
    SharedHelper.putKey(this, "device_id", deviceId);
}
```

don't initialize your CustomSharedPreferences inside FirebaseMessagingService class it may help you.