# Firebase Messaging Service new token

Tags: android, firebase, token

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceService extends FirebaseMessagingService
{
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);

        Log.d("DTAG","onNewToken: "+s);
    }
}
```

And in MainClass:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MainActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
            String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
            Log.d("DTAG","Token Main: "+newToken);

        }
    });
}
```

When I run my app **first** time the output that I get is:

```
D/DTAG: Token Main: token_a
D/DTAG: onNewToken: token_b
```

The **second** time I get:

```
D/DTAG: Token Main: token_a
```

Please help me get this...

```
 1. If I run for the first time, from where is gets token in MainClass (token_a)
 2. In case the token is renewed (onNewToken) which is token_b, why I still keep seeing token_a when launching the app in second time and what happened to token_b?
```

Comment: check this answer you will get idea how `onTokenRefresh/onNewToken`  is work https://stackoverflow.com/a/51835126/7666442

Comment: Ok, but the thing is, onNewToken returns token "a", and when launching the app on second time at mainClass i see it`s token "b". Should not it need to be replaced?