# error: not an enclosing class: MainActivity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is my code I am getting Error: error: not an enclosing class: MainActivity. Please help me what is the issue in my code.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingSerivce extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.e("NEW_TOKEN", s);
    }

    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    }
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MainActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult)
            {
                String updatedToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                Log.e("Updated Token",updatedToken);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: *`I am getting error`* What error?? you need to share that error with question

Comment: Can we use this one in FirebaseMessagingService? or do I need to create any other service class? please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we use this one in FirebaseMessagingService?

**No** the `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener()` method is used to get token inside activity

The **`onNewToken()`** method is used to get token inside **`FirebaseMessagingService`**

For more information check this answer of [Frank van Puffelen how `onNewToken` and `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()` will work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51835126/7666442)

Also check this  for [**`FirebaseMessagingService`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129304/7666442)

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MainActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult)
            {
                String updatedToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                Log.e("Updated Token",updatedToken);

            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am getting compile time error in my code when I use this function. error: <identifier> expected 
error: ';' expected 
error: illegal start of type 
error: '(' expected 
error: ';' expected 
error: ';' expected 
error: illegal start of type

Comment: @ThippeswamyHU share your current code where you are getting error also not make sure your adding `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener()` inside `onCreate()` method

Comment: Hi Nilesh, Now i have put that method inside the onCreate method. Previous error was resolved. Now I am getting this error error: not an enclosing class: MainActivity

Comment: @ThippeswamyHU share your activity code with question